# What is the meaning of a negative number when using getRGB()?

Tags: java, colors, rendering, rgb

I am new to color stuff, rendering etc. and watching a couple tutorial videos about rendering etc. My question is, when I call a `getRGB` method on a pixel, it returns a negative int. what is the meaning of this negative number? For example, when i call `getRGB` on a color with r: 186, g: 186, b: 186, it returns -4539718. How is this number related to its rgb value? I've made a couple of google search but was not successful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) method returns an `int` whose 4 bytes are the alpha, red, green, and blue components in that order.  Assuming that the pixel is not transparent, the alpha is 255 (0xFF).  It's the most significant byte in the `int`, and the first bit is set in that value.  Because in Java `int` values are signed according to [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the value is actually negative because that first bit is on.

Comment: Yes, it's a consequence of packing the 4 byte values into a 4-byte `int` and of signed Java `int` values.

Answer (score 2):

To get the color of a pixel:

```
Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(10,10));
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```