# Java color int to RGB in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, colors, rgba

I'm trying to use some Java Color int values from a database in Javascript. What's the correct way to convert the Java color int (like -2147473665) to an RGB string (like '#ffff00') using Javascript? Converting them straight to hex makes them all dark blue or black...

(Edit) The first answer helped, and I get colors other than black now, but they're still not the right hue. (I know the Google Maps API takes RGB, not HSV, so it's not that...)

```
function getClients() {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Client);

  query.each(function(client) {
    var clientName = client.get("clientName");
    var borderColor = '#' + (-client.get("borderColor")).toString(16);
    var fillColor = '#' + (-client.get("fillColor")).toString(16).substr(2);
    var outline = client.get("outline");

    console.log(client.get("borderColor"));
    console.log(client.get("borderColor").toString(16));
    console.log(hexToRGB(client.get("borderColor")));

    var clientPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: outline,
      strokeColor: borderColor,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    });

    clientPoly.setMap(mMap);
  });
}
```

For example, the int -16767233 should be navy blue, but it's showing up as yellow.

-16731137 should be light blue, but it's red

-1218518 should be orange, but it's blue

Correct colors:
[image: Correct colors]

This is what I get in JS with my current code
[image: This is what I get in JS with my current code]

Comment: What specific RGB value do you expect -16767233 to convert to?

Comment: I don't know the exact RGB value, that's why I need to convert them. It should be blue though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can convert the int into hex as follows :

```
var num = 2147473665;

var hexString = num.toString(16);
```

Hex string is now 7FFFD901

```
var alphalessHexString = hexString.substr(2, 6)
```

alphalessHexString is now FFD901

Put it all together in one line:

```
var num = 2147473665;
var alphalessHexString = num.toString(16).substr(2, 6)
```

alphalessHexString is now FFD901

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly... will I have to make a substring to get rid of the alpha?

Comment: I just edited the answer to be fully complete.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it either...
I'm getting values like -7f0000, -ff4c01, -ff5c2e, etc. - they're all dark gray or blue. They don't contain the right values as substrings either...
Maybe I can't convert it directly to a hex value?

The original int comes from a Java color object in ARGB format

Comment: Post your full code above. The example I posted works fine for me.

Comment: Andrew, you're starting with a negative number [because of the Java int type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605197/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-negative-number-when-using-getrgb). So in your JS perhaps convert it to a positive number first: `(-num).toString(16),substr(2)` and then -2147473665 becomes ffd901.

Comment: Nope :/ I'm getting the same numbers, but positive.
Colors look exactly the same

Comment: But ffd901 isn't dark gray or blue, it's yucky yellow.

Comment: Oh, duh, I forgot to add the hashtag to the string. I'm getting actual colors now, but they look like the opposite color... Is that what you were talking about in the part of the comment you deleted? lol

Answer (score 0):

If you have a color ARGB then what you have to do is

```
  int hx=-16767233 & 0x00ffffff;
  g2.setColor(new Color(hx));
  g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

now hx is RGB without the alpha.

Comment: This looks like Java... I'm trying to do this in Javascript